# xgboost could not be loaded In Mac

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost

I am trying to run below code. Which is the GitHub code of https://github.com/krishnaik06.

The link of jupyter notebook is given below.

https://github.com/krishnaik06/Credit_Card-Risk-assessment/blob/master/Credit%20Card%20Risk%20Assessment.ipynb

Where I was not able to load xgboost

Tried to run below cell, it is showing some error.

```
## Hyperparameter optimization using RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
import xgboost
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-60e28ccb95f6> in <module>
      1 ## Hyperparameter optimization using RandomizedSearchCV
      2 from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV
----> 3 import xgboost

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/__init__.py in <module>
      7 import os
      8 
----> 9 from .core import DMatrix, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Booster
     10 from .training import train, cv
     11 from . import rabit  # noqa

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in <module>
    171 
    172 # load the XGBoost library globally
--> 173 _LIB = _load_lib()
    174 
    175 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _load_lib()
    154     if not lib_success:
    155         libname = os.path.basename(lib_paths[0])
--> 156         raise XGBoostError(
    157             'XGBoost Library ({}) could not be loaded.\n'.format(libname) +
    158             'Likely causes:\n' +

XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (libxgboost.dylib) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libomp.dylib for Mac OSX, libgomp.so for Linux and other UNIX-like OSes). Mac OSX users: Run `brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['dlopen(/Users/danishali/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib\n  Referenced from: /Users/danishali/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.dylib\n  Reason: image not found']
```

What I tried:

1. Unninstalled anaconda
2. Insatlled anaconda with 64 bit python.

Still the same error

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I installed xgboost by pip, I got the same error.
Then, I uninstalled it by code:`pip uninstall xgboost`, and installed it by anaconda again by code:`conda install py-xgboost`.
Now I can `import xgboost`  with no error.